# Query between date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this data on the table;

```
STARTDATE   : ENDDATE     : FNAME : LNAME
Apr 1, 2013 : May 31, 2014: John  : Smith
Feb 1, 2013 : Jun 30, 2013: Gane  : Oxford
Jan 1, 2013 : Mar 11, 2013: Lloyd : White
```

I want to query those FNAME and LNAME that in between STARTDATE and ENDDATE. For example, today is May 23, 2013, I want to return all names between the startdate and enddate. On the example above; John Smith and Gane Oxford will be return.

```
SELECT fname, lname FROM table where NOW() BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
```

Comment: You forgot the question. But you told us a nice story.

Comment: You need to format the times so they'll have the same format. Consider converting them to unix timestamps.

Comment: when you handle with dates in mysql, i think it is best to store mysql date format to database.

Comment: That query in your question looks OK. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: yes,query looks ok but date format is questionable.

Comment: Mysql Date Format ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Use different date formats. 1. For storing to Database (ideally timestamp) and 2. for display on the screen (your format of choice).

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`table\`;` from console. I think your dates are not stored as string. Otherwise, you'd need to do a lot of changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT fname,lname FROM table_name where DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%b %d, %Y') between startdate AND endate;
```

`DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%b %d, %Y')`--- converts current date to your database date format as you mentioned `'Apr 1, 2013'`

Answer (score 1):

Use date format. Below is the example of mysql date format:

```
SELECT fname, lname FROM table where DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %d, %Y') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(startdate,'%b %d, %Y')  AND DATE_FORMAT(enddate,'%b %d, %Y')
```

try this if is works for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check like for current date:-

```
$date =  date(' F j\, Y'); //output :- May 23, 2013
```

and your query will be

```
SELECT fname, lname FROM table where $date BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
```